# Unsure of how to use attributes and methods in python

Tags: python, oop

I am currently working on an assignment where in a particular question I have to take a list of playing cards and, using a class, figure out if it is a `Royal Flush`.

The lecturer provided a 'skeleton' of code that I have to build the rest around without changing the parts he wrote.

```
#Lecturer created...
class PokerHand(Hand):

    def __init__(self, cards = list()):
        Hand.__init__(self, cards)

        self.handRank = 0
        self.hand = "High Card"

        #I have so far added this part...
        total_value = 0
        val_card_b4 = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            if Card.getValue(card) > val_card_b4:
                total_value += Card.getValue(card)
                val_card_b4 = Card.getValue(card)
                checkRoyalFlush()
        #...to here. However it throws an error that checkRoyalFlush isn't defined.        

    #The lecturer then had what is below already added.
    def checkHand(self):

        if self.checkRoyalFlush():
            self.handRank = 9
            self.hand = "Royal Flush"
            print("Test")
```

I have already created a `Card` class in an earlier question that allows me to create a card `object` get the value of the card (`A=11, 2-10 equal face value etc.`)

My problem is that, once I have checked the cards, I don't know how to 'activate' the `if self.checkRoyalFlush():` statement in the `checkHand` Method.

The code I have to get running is:

```
h1 = PokerHand([Card('hearts', '10'), Card('clubs', '10'),Card('hearts', '2'),Card('hearts', '3'),Card('spades', 'J')])
h1.show()
print(h1.checkHand())
```

I would like to understand how to get the if statement working, as I have spent a lond time researching and can't figure it out. I am only a beginner in python and new to the Object Oriented side of it.

Edit: I also don't know how to define 'checkRoyalFlush' without it getting more errors

Comment: I assume you need to write `self.checkRoyalFlush()` yourself. It is called by calling `checkHand`.

Comment: @Morgoth, yes, I should edit my Q to say that actually thnks. I don't actually know how to define it, or rather what to let it equal to initially

Comment: @Gurfuffle It appears to want to be a method. Define it similarly to your `def checkHand(self):` method

Comment: The call you have to `checkRoyalFlush()` should also be `self.checkRoyalFlush()` unless it is a global function. Hence the undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement such as `if self.checkRoyalFlush():` requires a boolean data type as a result, i.e. `True` or `False`. Your method needs to return either one of those values:

```
#Lecturer created...
class PokerHand(Hand):

    def __init__(self, cards = list()):
        # etc...

    def checkHand(self):
        # etc...

    # add your new method below the methods that already exist
    def checkRoyalFlush(self):
        # paste your code to check if it is a royal flush here
        # if it is a royal flush, then:
            return True
        # if it is NOT a royal flush, then:
            return False
```

Also you need to refer to your method as `self.checkRoyalFlush()` as it is a part of the class `PokerHand`. You aren't doing that in `checkHand()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your lecturer want method called `checkRoyalFlush()` which I'm assuming will return `true` if your hand is a royal flush or `false` if it isn't aren't.

Also note that I don't know how you set up your card class, and I don't know what you are calling the suit or value attribute. In the code below, I call `.suit` for the suit attribute and `.value` and the value attribute. Change it to whatever you made it as.

Consider code below:

```
class PokerHand:
    def __init__(self, cards = list()):
        #your init goes here as above

    def checkHand(self):
        #checkHand as above

    def checkRoyalFlush(self):          
        check_suit = cards[0].suit   #note I don't know what you are calling the suits and values in your hand, 
        values = ['A','K','Q','J','10'] #values we want to check against
        for each_card in cards:
            if not (each_card.typing == check_suit and each_card.value in values): 
                return False
            values.remove(each_card.value) #once we found a value we want to remove it from the possible list
        return True
```

The method `checkRoyalFlush()` will take one card's suit out of the cards list. Since a royal flush must have all the same suit it doesn't matter which card I choose. Here I choose the first card in the list.

Then I iterate through the `cards` list and check if NOT each of the card's typing is the same, and if each of the values are in the values list

if one card is does not match the requirement, it returns False.

We remove the value we checked so we can make sure it's 1 value and not duplicated values. 
If the for loop checking is finished with out returning False, we know  that it's a royal flush

Note this is not the most optimal way to do it, it's just one way that shows how it can be done rather clearly.